# Wired connection fails, connection from live cd does work

Tags: internet, live-cd, wired

My wired connection of my desktop has stopped working. It does connect to the internet when using the live cd. I'd like to know how to restore the connection. My system runs on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Look at the network logs (in both cases) with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager`.